# proxy_fcgi:error AH01071: Got error 'Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html/laravel/public/index.php (Permission denied)'

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have a website hosted using Apache in Azure. I was trying to access the website with http://example.com/laravel/public and it's showing me "Access denied" message and when I checked for the error log message, it's showing a proxy_fcgi:error AH01071 message as stated in the title. I am not sure if it's the htaccess configuration issue or other configuration which causes this issue. Please help.

In my .htaccess, I have the following configured:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like php-fpm does not have read permission on index.php
You could run the following on a terminal to know which user is actually running php-fpm :
`# ps aux | grep php-fpm | awk '{print $1}'`

You could then give permission on index.php to this specific user with the following (replace <php_fpm_user> with the result of the first command):
`# setfacl -m u:<php_fpm_user>:r /var/www/html/laravel/public/index.php`

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case I get 4 outputs when running this script: 
# root root wwwrun wwwrun 
But why 4 outputs and should the owner be: "wwwrun" (php user) just "root" (I guess not). Where can I manage this php-fpm "allowed-users"-access?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases this can be caused by SELINUX being set to ENFORCING... you can either disabled SELINUX (reboot required) or add the corresponding SELINUX policy.